# How to set a password field in WPCF7 (Contact Form 7)

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 in a wordpress site to build a sign-in form. In my form I'd like to add a password field but it seems that this field is missing in this plugin.

Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone faces the same issue as mentioned above, (although not recommended) there exist solutions. You can find one such solution over [here](http://smallenvelop.com/how-to-get-password-fields-in-contact-form-7/).

In short, you need to add the following script to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

function cfp($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array( "id" => "", "title" => "", "pwd" => "" ), $atts));

    if(empty($id) || empty($title)) return "";

    $cf7 = do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 404 "Not Found"]');

    $pwd = explode(',', $pwd);
    foreach($pwd as $p) {
        $p = trim($p);

        $cf7 = preg_replace('/<input type="text" name="' . $p . '"/usi', '<input type="password" name="' . $p . '"', $cf7);
    }

    return $cf7;
}

    add_shortcode('cfp', 'cfp');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is outside the scope of CF7 it is just used for sending emails and with the open nature of email it is not advisable to send anything with passwords attached or in content.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make this code works:

```
function cfp($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array( "id" => "", "title" => "", "pwd" => "" ), $atts));

    if(empty($id) || empty($title)) return "";

$cf7 = do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="'. $id .'" title="' . $title . '"]');


    $pwd = explode(',', $pwd);
    foreach($pwd as $p) {
        $p = trim($p);

        $cf7 = preg_replace('/<input type="text" name="' . $p . '"/usi', '<input type="password" name="' . $p . '"', $cf7);
    }

    return $cf7;
}
add_shortcode('cfp', 'cfp');
```